# Grounding Metal Garage with Subpanel

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding

For the subpanel I am installing in my metal garage (concrete floor), I have sunk an eight foot copper-coated rod next to the outside wall and adjacent to the panel which is on the inside of the building. For secondary grounding, can I bond the ground wire to the building's frame, rather than run the wire underground to another grounding rod?

The garage was installed in recent years by the previous owner. He installed plumbing pipes, but did not connect them. I don't have his plans and he is now deceased. I wonder if his unmet intentions included installing electrical.

Is there any way I can determine whether or not the building is grounded in the absence of finding a connection to ground?

---

EDIT:  I agree that there is some ambiguity in my question. My first objective is to avoid sinking another grounding rod. I realize that I cannot use the metal frame of the building as a ground unless I can establish that it, in fact, is grounded. Since I've received no indication that there is a method by which I can do that (unless I find an existing connection to a grounding rod - unlikely, since the proper means of grounding when the concrete pour took place is now invisible), my second objective is to ensure that I can use the metal frame as a path to ground by bonding to it another grounding rod at any convenient location and bonding the building to the existing rod, as well. (That is, can I avoid running wire between the grounding rods and use the building instead?)
Incidentally, the partial plumbing install has no metal parts; no help from it.

Comment: Are the pipes metal?  Metal pipes are still a code compliant grounding electrode. Could you use the frame? Possibly but you would need proof that the steel was bonded to the rebar, I cad weld on commercial jobs and photograph as the structural and electrical inspectors are not always the same if you do use the structural through the slab a #4 conductor is required where #6 is ok with rod , pipe or plate electrodes, I show them the photos if there is a question that may not work for a home owner.

Comment: The wording of the question has some ambiguity. Structural metal itself is not a usable grounding electrode, it becomes and usable electrode when in encased with earth or encased with concrete in contact with earth.  Structural metal is required to be bonded, so it is allowed to be used as a grounding electrode conductor to connect supplemental grounding electrodes, such as a ground rod or buried metal water pipe (which metal piping is required to be bonded even if not buried and serving as a grounding electrode)

Comment: Is there any evidence of an Ufer ground in the concrete pour?  If I were king, there'd be a $500 excise tax on any concrete pour done without including an Ufer ground.

Comment: Yes, what material is the pipe carrying water to the garage made from?

Comment: I believe the reason people usually drop two rods in cases where only one may be required is it's cheaper, safer and easier than making the measurements necessary to establish a single rod is adequate.  I've done those measurements on commercial projects, and the tool wasn't something you could rent from Home Depot so arrangements were made to borrow it from another electrical company who had one on site.  If the earth in the area tends to make grounding difficult, it may be prudent and cost effective to go so far as to add bentonite clay or other precautions to the two electrodes.